How should we do two stage regression when the dependent variable in second stage is categorical variable (not just binary)?
I came to know about  that Newey’s (1987) two step estimator which can be used like 2SLS when endogenous regressor is continuous and main dependent variable (in the second stage) is binary. However, in my research question of interest, my second stage regression has dependent variable that is categorical (1 if some one completed graduation and above, 2 if individual completed high school, 3 if individual completed middle school, 4 if no formal education). But my instrument and endogenous independent variables are continuous.
Is there any way to conduct two step estimation when dependent variable is beyond binary?
